# IElement, extract Element from GroupElement nested in GroupElement

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

As per title.

I am trying to extract Element from nested GroupElement. I can not find any code sample for that. Please refer to one or point me in to right direction, how to do that.

It sounds simple but turned out to be nightmare. I cannot figure out how whole mechonism of Group in the Group works. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some VBA code to get you going, it is expecting the page layout to have only one element in it that is a bunch of graphics grouped together. The code finds the group element and then prints to the debug window the name property. You could adapt this code to test if the element in the GroupElement is in fact a GroupElement itself.

```vb
Public Sub test()
Dim pMXD As IMxDocument
Set pMXD = ThisDocument
Dim pPageLayout As IPageLayout3
Set pPageLayout = pMXD.PageLayout
Dim pGraphicsContainer As IGraphicsContainer
Set pGraphicsContainer = pPageLayout
pGraphicsContainer.Reset
Dim pElement As IElement
Set pElement = pGraphicsContainer.Next
If TypeOf pElement Is IGroupElement Then
    Debug.Print "GroupElement found"
    Dim pGroupElement As IGroupElement3
    Set pGroupElement = pElement
    Dim pEnumElement As IEnumElement
    Set pEnumElement = pGroupElement.Elements
    pEnumElement.Reset
    Dim pElementProp As IElementProperties3
    Dim pElement2 As IElement
    Dim pElement_tomove As IElement
    Set pElement2 = pEnumElement.Next
    Do While Not pElement2 Is Nothing
        Set pElementProp = pElement2
        Debug.Print pElementProp.Name
        If pElementProp.Name = "X" Then
            ' Found an element with name set to X, this is the one we want to move out of the group
            Set pElement_tomove = pElement2
        End If
        Set pElement2 = pEnumElement.Next
    Loop

    ' Using MoveElementFromGroup to move element out of group to order position 1 in the graphicsContainer
    ' which is pointing to the PageLayout.
    pGraphicsContainer.MoveElementFromGroup pGroupElement, pElement_tomove, 1

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I can find those Elements and set IElementsProperties, but I can not GraphicContainer.MoveFromGroup. Actually I can do it for the first one, but rest fails(silently). So my question should rather be, how Groups in Group are constructed, what does change when you extract element from group, etc.?

Comment: I have updated my code example to show use of MoveElementFromGroup method.